# MS Access .mdb files in Mac OS X (or Mono)

Tags: macos, ms-access, mono

Whats the best way to write to MS Access (.mdb) databases on Mac OS? I have a project that I'd like to port (quickly) to Mac OS and I'm thinking about using something cross-platform such as Mono.

Can anybody recommend a good place to start? Do I *really* have to scrap my .mdb files and export into something else?

I quite like the .mdb files on Windows given that the Jet database engine is pretty much part of all Windows versions these days.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not switch to sqlite for example?

Comment: +1 for SQLite. Drop Access as soon as possible. Also, you can easily embed sqlite.dll in your application for portable Windows installation, the library is really small.

Comment: Uh, Access is not involved -- only Jet.

Answer (score 0):

[actual technologies](http://www.actualtech.com/download.php) has an odbc driver on the mac for mdb.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cloud version of MS Access available. (http://www.apponfly.com/en/micro...)

They provide 30day free trial via remote desktop connection.